# Are some HDD's incompatible with Linux?

Tags: hard-drive, compatibility

Having spent nearly 20 hours over the last two days trying to install two different distros of Linux (settling my attentions on Ubuntu) on two seperate Western Digital WD Blue WD10EZEX (1TB) Hard Drives, I've started to wonder whether or not certain Hard Drives are compatible with installations of Linux.

And, if certain Hard Drives are incompatible, how would you go about telling whether or not they were? Would it be 'labelled on the box', so to speak?

Comment: That's a 6G byte/sec drive, is your controller 6G?  You might have to jumger the drive for 3G or maybe master/slave ...  Of course, it could be a bad cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't believe this is a question with a viable answer, here goes nothing:

Some drives in my experience have failed because they were bad out of the box, others because of age. I usually recommend WD for disc drives because I haven't had many issues. If you were to ask for help installing Ubuntu can gave the errors you were having maybe someone could better assist.

That said, I have only ever seen the Tux-Approved logo ONCE and that was on a Toshiba drive in 2008. Once again I believe this question would be better placed in Meta AskUbuntu

Comment: Meta is for questions about the Site itself.  Questions about ubuntu are here on the main-site.  I dont see anything in this question that relates to the running of the Site and as such should not be moved to Meta.

Comment: @psusi and Cole, Thank you. And I actually have asked around for advice on what to do, and found what I believe to be the problem...I just wanted to rule out one possible issue, thus the thread. Thank you again for all of your comments, they were quite helpful.

Comment: @WelshHeron How did you fix it? I'm having the same issue using the same HDD!

Comment: The best way in response to these of low relativity is to ignore them, in terms of the Internet rule.

Answer (score 1):

No; a drive is a drive.  You may want to instead ask a question about your specific issues to get help solving them.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part drives are compatible because they just require a standard driver, however there are some drives out there that require special drivers (eg gigabyte i-ram). I would not expect yours to be one as it's a standard sata drive. It's far more likely that your storage controller/raid card isn't supported. If it is your drive rather than controller then in your bios or UEFI you may be able to set your storage controller to act in legacy IDE mode, this can sometimes alleviate driver related issues, but it does come at the price of performance (minor loss), and lack of hot swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Not so, Debian jessie and the Seagate portable Extension hd is not compatible with automounting at bootup. It lterally takes hours to boot it and access is dead-snail slow. There are a number of blogs and os support support sites which are discussing this. I tried to use with Jessie and can personally confirm this. I have found no solutions but a work arond is to manually unmount and mount/remount after booting. I have found no contribution to the discussions from Seagate.

Comment: You said: "There are a number of blogs and os support support sites which are discussing this."  Providing a link or two would be helpful to readers.

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/unable-to-mount-seagate-1tb-usb-expansion-drive-851682/ , http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/005878en?language=en_US&key=ka030000000thGvAAI&kb=n&wwwlocale=en-us